# Compare two files using awk command recursively

Tags: shell, awk

I want to compare two files,
1) Compare Each query result.
2) Compare Only first row of the Query output
3) Compare Time (3rd column), First file time is lesser than 2nd file then print the PO_NUM else do nothing.

File1:

```
C:\script>call transaction 1OPOP

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                        DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1OPOP           2012-08-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1OPOP           2013-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232325    1OPOP           2014-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232326    1OPOP           2015-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE
4 record(s) selected.

C:\script>call transaction 1XDXD

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                        DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1XDXD           2012-07-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1XDXD           2013-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232325    1XDXD           2014-08-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
3 record(s) selected.

C:\script>call transaction 1IOIO

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                        DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1IOIO           2011-06-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1IOIO           2012-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
2 record(s) selected.
```

File 2:

```
C:\script>call transaction 1OPOP

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                    DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1OPOP           2012-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1OPOP           2013-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232325    1OPOP           2014-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232326    1OPOP           2015-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE
4 record(s) selected.

C:\script>call transaction 1XDXD

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                    DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1XDXD           2012-08-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1XDXD           2013-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232325    1XDXD           2014-08-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
3 record(s) selected.

C:\script>call transaction 1IOIO

C:\script>Select ID, PO_ID, TIME, DES From Table
ID          PO_NUM          TIME                DES         
-------     ------------    ---------------             -----
11232323    1IOIO           2011-05-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
11232324    1IOIO           2012-09-01-23.02.50.040000  SAMPLE  
2 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Can you show us what input you expect and what did you manage to do so far ?

Comment: If you can't reduce and simplify this any, then the number of people willing to try to figure out what you're trying to do is going to be pretty small, I expect. Can't you just post a couple of input files with a couple of lines each and a couple of fields on each line that REPRESENTS your real problem so it's simple for us to understand and you can extrapolate from the answers you get and apply to your real input?

Comment: I meant output. But what said @EdMorton was in my mind, but I was too lazy to write it.

Comment: from First query we need to take value 2012-08-01-23.02.50.040000 from file and compare with value form 2nd file first query 2012-09-01-23.02.50.040000. Here file1's value is greater than file2's value. Same applicable for 2nd query as well.   In 3rd query first result(row), pick the value 2011-06-01-23.02.50.040000 and compare against 2011-05-01-23.02.50.040000. Here file1's value is lesser than file'2 value So we need to print po_num 1IOIO. Data is varied based on MONTHS in the above example.

Comment: What is the format of the end of the timestamp? E.g. : `23.02.50.040000`. Is it hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds?

Comment: Ok, and the date is year-month-day or year-day-month?

Comment: @Ragu, we meant that we'd like you to edit your question to make it clearer. It's just a way to increase the probability of having good answers to your problem.

Comment: year-month-day.24hr.mm.ss.millisec

Comment: @Ragu Ok, then you have to fix the format string in my answer below. I assumed year-day-month, so change it to `%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`.

Comment: I have modified, its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk example:

```
awk '/^---/ {b=1;next} b==1{if(NR==FNR) a[$2]=$3; else if(a[$2]<$3) print $2; b=0}' file1 file2
1OPOP
1XDXD
```

Here's the breakdown:

- set b=1 when the line starts with "---"
- when b==1 expect to process the first row of data
- either store the time in `a[]` under PO_NUM for `file1` or compare it lexographically against time in file2's first and print accordingly.

If the IDs have to be matched the awk would get slightly more complicated.

---

Here's a slightly more complicated version that lets the `ID`s of the query results be out of order in the 2nd file compared to the first:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if($0 ~ /^---/) {b=1} else if(b==1) {a[$1$2]=$3; b=0} next} $1$2 in a {if(a[$1$2]<$3) print $2}' file1 file2
```

The main difference is that the key in `a` is based on both the `ID` of the first result from each query in `file1` and the `PO_NUM`. For the second file all the entries in the result are checked for a matching `ID` and `PO_NUM` combination in the array.  Also, since `b` only matters in the first file now, I re-arranged the conditional tests a little.

Comment: Thanks lot for providing this awk script. its working fine as I expected

Comment: HI n0741337, Can you please provide how can I compare when the Query is not ordered? if the 2nd file's queries are NOT as same order in the 1st file, Then is it possible to match the PO_NUM and print the result?

Comment: To be clear - are you saying that the responses in the `Select` statement don't have a matching first `ID`?  For example for `1OPOP`, the 2nd file's first entry is `11232323` in your question, but it could instead be `11232326`?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes I mean something else. I have 2 questions for you: 1) print $2 prints PO_NUM from 2nd File. How to print PO_NUM from first file.     2) When PO_NUM is not in the same order, user executes the query in wrong order. Assume like file1's PO_NUM order "1OPOP", "1XDXD", "1IOIO" File2's PO_NUM order "1OPOP", "1IOIO", "1XDXD". Here in 2nd file 2nd and 3rd transaction and query & output swapped its position. So in this case program has to run entire file for searching the matching PO_NUM. I know its difficult to do. But time being please answer first question.

Comment: `$2` is a match point and it doesn't matter if it's being printed from `file2` as `1OPOP` from `file1` has to match `1OPOP` from `file2`.  It *has* to match or else nothing will be printed at all.  The second awk I'm showing will already allow the transactions from the second file to be out of order.  However, I suspect you want to preserve the order of the transactions from the `file1` in the output (`1OPOP`, `1XDXD`) which the second awk won't do.  Let me know.

Comment: Yes $2 is a matching point, suppose if the po_num is not matching(between file1 and file2), Then also is it possible to compare the time & print the $2 from first file? Some worst case I want to print like this.. is it possible? Some time order is not maintained So we need to follow the above approach.

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer's second awk?

Comment: Hi lets make the awk simple,  instead of storing $1 and $2 in the array, just store the index of the query, compare the time and display the PO_NUM from first file. (No need to take care of order). for file1 "1OPOP" index is 0, "1XDXD" index is 1, "1IOIO" index is 2 etc..

Comment: Sorry I did not try your 2nd awk, Let me try it. But as per your explanation, 2nd query may fail for my previous case(just want to store the index of the query in the array)

Comment: @ n0741337 I have tried your 2nd AWK. its not working when there no matching PO_NUM. can you please provide AWK based on Index of the Query? Please let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I have to stop here for better input.  You've given me conflicting requirements:  transactions in `file2` can be in any order versus any `PO_NUM` not in file2 defaults to an in-order `PO_NUM` from `file1`.  Please edit your question with desired inputs AND outputs for good and bad file2 examples.  You can trim the input files down to just the basics(for example maybe just the first 3 lines of any `Select` (including headers) for each query).  Being clear in examples will help you clarify the question's wording.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;

use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use Time::Piece;

my $fmt='%Y-%d-%m-%H.%M.%S';
my @files=qw(file1 file2);
my @data;
for my $file (@files) {
    my $str=read_file($file);
    my @a=$str=~/-----\s*\n(.*?)\n\d+ record/sg;
    my $i=0;
    for (@a) {
        my $line=@{[split (/\n/)]}[0];
        my @fld=split(" ",$line);
        my $d=$fld[2];
        my ($date)=$d=~/(.*)\.[^.]*$/;
        $data[$i]={} if ! defined $data[$i];
        $data[$i]->{$file}{time}=Time::Piece->strptime($date, $fmt);
        $data[$i]->{id}=$fld[1];
        $i++;
    }      
}
for my $row (@data) {
    my $t1=$row->{file1}->{time};
    my $t2=$row->{file2}->{time};
    if ($t1>$t2) {
        say $row->{id};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot for providing this script. its working fine.